# Function argument used but not passed

Tags: bash

What happens if I define a bash (or any other shell) function that takes an argument, but don't pass an argument when make a call to it? Is an empty string guaranteed to be passed by default?

```
function test() {
  echo $1
}
test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html#EX17

> If a script expects a command-line parameter but is invoked without one, this may cause a null variable assignment, generally an undesirable result. One way to prevent this is to append an extra character to both sides of the assignment statement using the expected positional parameter.

Comment: Hihi :) I never had to deal with more than 9 arguments in bash. I edited it to `${N}` for short, but then I found the above statement in the docs. Seems to be the correct answer to your question.

Comment: The answer is yes the same way that using any other unassigned variable expands to the empty string. That statement is discussing a specific "error" that can occur for a missing argument and is a particularly poor "solution" for the problem (the final "However" note is much better).

Comment: @EtanReisner You are right. I can't delete this answer at the moment since it is accepted-

Comment: I haven't seen that "Advanced" guide in years.  :-)  Note that it misses on a number of "best practices", like quoting your variables and validating your input.  These days, usage like `[ -n "${N}" ]` is considered safe, at least in bash. And because `[` and `[[` are bash builtins, behaviour should be consistent and portable.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `$1` is `unset`. Unused positional parameters are `unset` by default, which is slightly different than being set to `null`.  If you wrote `foo=""`, then `$foo` would be `null`.

One of the differences is that referencing an `unset` parameter will result in an error if you have the `nounset` shell attribute set (`set -o nounset`).

For more information:

- [Difference between unset and empty variables in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406858/difference-between-unset-and-empty-variables-in-bash)
- [Using unset vs. setting a variable to empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262696/using-unset-vs-setting-a-variable-to-empty)
- [How to check if a variable is set in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash)