# Checking the success of a command in a bash `if [ .. ]` statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am trying to automate our application backup. Part of the process is to check the exit status of `egrep` in an `if` statement:

```
if [ ! -f /opt/apps/SiteScope_backup/sitescope_configuration.zip ] ||
   [ egrep -i -q "error|warning|fatal|missing|critical" "$File" ]
then 
  echo "testing"
fi
```

I expected it to output `testing` because the file exists and `egrep` returns success, but instead I'm getting an error:

```
-bash: [: too many arguments
```

I tried with all kinds of syntax - additional brackets, quotes etc but error still persists.

Please help me in understanding where I am going wrong.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: that doesn't mean it "works".

Comment: `egrep` shouldn't be surrounded with brackets.

Comment: David : try it with -f on a file that exists in your system, and you will get the same error than Abhinandan.

Comment: Thanks ALL for your reply. @kichik - Removing brackets around egrep worked.. Thanks much:)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are making the common mistake of assuming that `[` is part of the `if` statement's syntax.  It is not; the syntax of `if` is simply

```
if command; then
    : # ... things which should happen if command's result code was 0
else
    : # ... things which should happen otherwise
fi
```

One of the common `command`s we use is `[` which is an alias for the command `test`.  It is a simple command for comparing strings, numbers, and files.  It accepts a fairly narrow combination of arguments, and tends to generate confusing and misleading error messages if you don't pass it the expected arguments.  (Or rather, the error messages are adequate and helpful once you get used to it, but they are easily misunderstood if you're not used.)

Here, you want to check the result of the command `egrep`:

```
if [ ! -f /opt/apps/SiteScope_backup/sitescope_configuration.zip ] ||
   egrep -i -q "error|warning|fatal|missing|critical" "$File"
then
    echo "testing"
fi
```

In the general case, `command` can be a pipeline or a list of commands; then, the exit code from the final command is the status which `if` will examine, similarly to how the last command in a script decides the exit status from the script.

These compound commands can be arbitrarily complex, like

```
if read thing
    case $thing in
      '' | 'quit') false;;
      *) true;;
    esac
then ...
```

but in practice, you rarely see more than a single command in the `if` statement (though it's not unheard of; your compound statement with `||` is a good example!)

Just to spell this out,

```sh
if [ egrep foo bar ]
```

is running `[` aka `test` on the arguments `egrep foo bar`. But `[` without options only accepts a single argument, and then checks whether or not that argument is the empty string. (`egrep` is clearly not an empty string. Quoting here is optional, but would perhaps make it easier to see:

```sh
if [ "egrep" ]; then
    echo "yes, 'egrep' is not equal to ''"
fi
```

This is obviously silly in isolation, but should hopefully work as an illustrative example.)

The historical reasons for `test` as a general kitchen sink of stuff the authors didn't want to make part of the syntax of `if` is one of the less attractive designs of the original Bourne shell.  Bash and `zsh` offer alternatives which are less unwieldy (like the `[[` double brackets in bash), and of course, POSIX `test` is a lot more well-tempered than the original creation from Bell Labs.

Comment: This is an adaptation of [this earlier answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10586252/874188) to a vaguely similar question.

Comment: Nit pick: the `if` syntax is actually `if list of commands; then` and the last command determines the status. And a *command* may be a pipe.

Comment: @Jens Thanks, very astute! Updated.

Comment: Can anyone explain me why in other languages 0 is considered a false (and other numbers true) and instead here 0 is considered as a truthy value? thank you

Comment: @silvanasono Quick googling gets me [Why 0 is true but false is 1 in the shell?](/questions/2933843/why-0-is-true-but-false-is-1-in-the-shell)

Comment: Tangentially, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern