# Bash: Use directory as variable

Tags: bash, backup

I'm writing a script to check if there actually is a directory that has content and a normal size, and see if there is a directory older then 36 hours, if not it should alert me.

However I'm having trouble using the directories as variable.
When I execute the script it returns: `./test.sh: line 5: 1: No such file or directory`.
I tried `ALLDIR=$(ls /home/customers/*/` as well but returned the same error.

What am I doing wrong? Below is the script.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

```
#!/bin/bash
ALLDIR=$(find * /home/customers/*/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2)
for DIR in ${ALLDIR}
do
  if [[ $(find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*' ! -mtime -36 | wc -l = <1 ) ]]; then
  mail -s "No back-ups found today at $DIR! Please check the issue!" test@example.com
  exit 1
  fi
done

for DIR in ${ALLDIR}
do
  if [[ $(find "$DIR" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -ks {} + | awk '$1 <= 50' | cut -f 2- ) ]]; then
  mail -s "Backup directory size is too small for $DIR, please check the issue!" test@example.com
  exit 1
  fi
done
```

Comment: The problem comes from ``wc -l = <1``.  Do you want to compare the output of  ``wc -l `` to 1 ?

Comment: paranthesis usage is wrong in `$(find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*' ! -mtime -36 | wc -l = <1 )`. `[[ $(find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*' ! -mtime -36 | wc -l) -le 1 ]]`

Comment: @Anubis no, don't do that.

Comment: @xiawi, no don't do that either!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start, to loop through all directories a fixed level deep, use this:

```
for dir in /home/customers/*/*/*/
```

A pattern ending in a slash `/` will only match directories.

Note that `$dir` is a lowercase variable name, don't use uppercase ones as they may clash with shell internal/environment variables.

Next, your conditions are a bit broken - you don't need to use a `[[` test here:

```
if ! find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -mtime -36 | grep -q .
```

If anything is found, `find` will print it and `grep` will quietly match anything, so the pipeline will exit successfully. The `!` at the start negates the condition, so the `if` branch will only be taken when this doesn't happen, i.e. when nothing is found. `-name '*'` is redundant.

You can do something similar with the second `if`, removing the `[[` and `$()` and using `grep -q .` to test for any output. I guess the `cut` part is redundant too.

Comment: Great answer! However `grep -q .` can't be used here as he is checking whether there are 'single' or 'no' outputs right.

Comment: As I understand, they want to check whether at least one directory exists or not, so it should be fine.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why using lower case for variables?

And is `[[` practically never used?

Comment: @Florius The lower case thing is covered well elsewhere, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/2088135. It's a good idea to use `[[` in many situations but this isn't one of them! `if` doesn't always go with `[` or `[[`, it works with any command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371221/bash-if-statement-too-many-arguments explains how `[` (and by extension also `[[`) isn't what you want here.