# Using netcat to issue a http get request in bash

Tags: linux, bash, http, netcat

I have written the following script (it does not support index yet). The issue I am having is regarding using netcat to load the page. I can do this manually using the command line but when I try to have my script issue the exact same commands I can it does nothing without error. The only possible thing I can think is that my output is going somewhere else?

```
#!/bin/bash
PORT=80

while [ true ]
do
    echo "Type the address you wish to visit then, followed by [ENTER]:"
    read address
    path=${address#*/}
    domain=${address%%/*}
    nc $domain $PORT
    printf "GET /$path HTTP/1.1\n" 
    printf "Host: $domain\n" 
    printf "\n" 
    printf "\n" 
done
```

Comment: `while [ true ]` doesn't do what you think it does, though it does actually happen to work.  You mean `while true` or `while [ "nonempty-string-is-still-nonempty" ]`

Comment: Tangentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371221/bash-if-statement-too-many-arguments; also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc isn't really about this, but should hopefully help clarify your mental model of how scripts work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nc` works by copying standard input to the given address:port, and copying whatever it reads from there to standard output.

```
{
  printf "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n" "$path"
  printf "Host: %s\r\n" "$domain"
  printf "\r\n" 
  printf "\r\n"
} | nc "$domain" "$port"
```

- HTTP requires `\r\n` at the end of each line. Some servers accept just `\n` but some stick to the letter of the law and accept only `\r\n` as specified.
- You need to send these lines to the standard input of `nc`.
- It is better to use `printf "Get %s HTTP/1.1\r\n" "$path" because`$path`may contain`%`signs and that would confuse`printf`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the request header to the standard input of `nc`.

One way to do that is input redirection:

```
while true
do
    echo "Type the address you wish to visit then, followed by [ENTER]:"
    read address
    path=${address#*/}
    domain=${address%%/*}
    nc $domain $PORT <<EOF
GET /$path
Host: $domain

EOF
done
```