# For every line in a file, determine if string is present within another file

Tags: bash

I have a tab delimited text file (animals.txt) with five columns:

```
302947298 2340974238 0 0 cat
345098948 8345988989 0 0 dog
098982388 2098340923 0 0 fish
932840923 0923840988 0 0 parrot
```

I have another file, mess.txt.gz, which is compressed using GNU zip (.gz file).
It basically looks like a massive string of letters:

```
sdihfoiahdfosparrotdhiafoihsdfoijaslkdogoieufoiweuf
```

Basically, for every line in the tab delimited text file, I want to see
if any of the animal names are present within this .gz file.

Ideally, it would return something like this:

```
302947298 2340974238 0 0 cat no
345098948 8345988989 0 0 dog yes
098982388 2098340923 0 0 fish no
932840923 0923840988 0 0 parrot yes
```

At the moment I am doing the following:

```
gunzip -cd mess.txt.gz | grep cat
gunzip -cd mess.txt.gz | grep dog
```

To automate it, I've tried the following:

```
cat animals.txt | awk '{print $5}' > animal_names.txt

cat animal_names.txt | while read line 
do
   gunzip -cd mess.txt.gz | grep $line > output.txt
done
```

I've also tried:

```
cat animal_names.txt | while read line 
do
   if [ gunzip -cd mess.txt.gz | grep $line ]
   then
     echo "Yes"
   else
     echo "No"
   fi
   ; do
done > output.txt
```

What is the best way to do this in bash?

Comment: As an aside, `if [ gunzip -cd mess.txt.gz | grep $line ]` is a syntax error; even if it wasn't, it just checks whether `gunzip` etc is not an empty string, which of course it isn't. Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371221/checking-the-success-of-a-command-in-a-bash-if-statement

Comment: Perhaps see also why you may want to avoid a [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass all the search strings to `zgrep -Ff -` in one pass:

```sh
cut -f5 animals.txt |
zgrep -Ff - mess.txt.gz
```

The `-F` option says to look for literal strings, not regular expressions (avoids false positives if the input contains dots or other regex metacharacters, and besides, will be significantly faster) and `-f -` says to read the search patterns from standard input (i.e. from the pipe from `cut`).

If you want a list of the matched animals, add an `-o` option and a brief postprocessing step;

```sh
cut -f5 animals.txt |
zgrep -Ff - -o mess.txt.gz |
sort | uniq -c
```

You can replace `| uniq -c` with just `-u` if you don't care how many there were of each.

This works as intended on Linux with GNU `grep`, but macOS (and thus probably generally *BSD) `grep -o` only prints the first match in each input line when combined with `-f -`.  If you need *BSD portability, I'd go with either of the other solutions here (currently there's one for `sed` and one for Awk).

Comment: This would show, which animals are in mess.txt, but is missing the _yes/no_ information the OP wants to know. Of course this is a mere cosmetic issue; such a table could be generated easily afterwards, based on the output of zgrep.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks; added a brief postprocessing step which doesn't do exactly that, but at least should offer some direction.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk` solution with `gzcat`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR==NR {s=s $0; next} {print $0, (index(s, $NF) > 1 ? "yes" : "no")}' <(gzcat mess.txt.gz) animals.txt

302947298  2340974238  0  0  cat     no
345098948  8345988989  0  0  dog     yes
098982388  2098340923  0  0  fish    no
932840923  0923840988  0  0  parrot  yes
```

A more readable form:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
FNR == NR {
   s = s $0
   next
}
{
   print $0, (index(s, $NF) > 1 ? "yes" : "no")
}
' <(gzcat mess.txt.gz) animals.txt
```

Comment: I like this solution but when I tried it on my files it returned "no" for every option

Comment: I tested it on your provided sample data and got this output shown in my answer

Comment: Apologies, I was using zcat instead of gzcat.

Comment: On some systems zcat works fine with gz files but I am on OSX so had to use gzcat

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```sh
gunzip -cd mess.txt.gz | grep "$(< animals.txt sed -e 's/.*\t//' | sed -z 's/\n/\\|/g;s/\\|$//')"
```

It is basically the version of your

```sh
gunzip -cd mess.txt.gz | grep dog
```

where, instead of `dog`, the regex `dog\|cat\|whatever` is generated from the file `animals.txt`.

My command should give you the output that you get with the example you write after

> To automate it, I've tried the following:

with which you *don't* end up with the result you refer to as ideal.

Comment: `sed -z` is a GNU extension, and not portable to other platforms. You could probably refactor the second `sed` script to work portably; or just replace it with `tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|$//;s/|\\&/g'`. The whitespace in the first `sed` script should be a literal tab to work properly with tab-delimited input.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the tab-related bug. As regards the rest, your surely right.

Answer (score 1):

Many nice answers here, and a [very good one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67833965/3641635) from @triplee.

Just adding the *'in memory'* bash way :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
search() {
  local patterns="$2"
  local string="$(gunzip -cd $1)"
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    local pattern="${line/[^$'\t']*$'\t'/}"
    local suffix="no"
    [ "${string/${pattern}/}" != "${string}" ] && suffix="yes"
    echo "${line} ${suffix}"
  done < "${patterns}"
}
search mess.txt animals.txt
```

The goal here is to limit I/O, one read from the gziped mess.txt, one read from  animals and match in memory with strings patterns.

Comment: You want `read -r` to not mangle backslashes in the input, and probably `IFS=` to preserve whitespace. But keeping the entirely `gzip` file in memory seems deeply flawed, and doing this in pure shell is borderline madness anyway.

Comment: @tripleee You're right, thanks, edited.  That's mainly to show that it's possible, which does not imply that it's whishable ^^