# ash: -c: unknown operand

Tags: shell, wc, ash

I'm trying to run a ash script that constantly checks how many characters are in a file and execute some code if it reaches at least 170 characters or if 5 seconds have passed. To do that I wanted to call `wc -c`, however it keeps telling me it has an unknown operand.

The code:

```
#!/bin/ash
while true; do
secs=5
endTime=$(( $(date +%s) + secs ))
while [ /usr/bin/wc -c < "/tmp/regfile_2" -gt 170 ] || [ $(date +%s) -lt $endTime ]; do

#more code
```

It's output is `ash: -c: unknown operand`

Comment: You have `ash` (sic), not `bash`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking the success of a command in a bash \`if \[ .. \]\` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371221/checking-the-success-of-a-command-in-a-bash-if-statement)

Comment: @Roadowl `ash` is another shell.

Comment: (Unintentional near-pun there; `ash` is the [Almquist Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell); it doesn't literally stand for **A**nother **Sh**ell.)

Comment: The question was originally incorrectly tagged [tag:bash] [tag:ash]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check whether the output from `wc` meets a specific condition. To do that, you need to actually execute `wc`, just like you already do with `date` to examine its output.

```sh
while [ $(wc -c < "/tmp/regfile_2") -gt 170 ] ||
      [ $(date +%s) -lt $endTime ]; do
    # ...stuff
```

Notice the `$(command substitution)` around the `wc` command.

As you can see from the answer to the proposed duplicate [Checking the success of a command in a bash `if [ .. ]` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371221/checking-the-success-of-a-command-in-a-bash-if-statement) your current command basically checks whether the static string `/usr/bin/wc` is non-empty; the `-c` after this string is indeed unexpected, and invalid syntax.

(It is unclear why you hardcode the path to `wc`; probably just make sure your `PATH` is correct before running this script. There are situations where you do want to hardcode paths, but I'm guessing this isn't one of them; if it is, you should probably hardcode the path to `date`, too.)