# Bash - Only When Output Is Terminal

Tags: bash, pipe, tty

I want to have a section in my code that only executes, when the output is printed in the terminal, not piped or redirected into a text file or other program. 
I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(tty "-s") ]]; then
  printf "You are using a terminal.\n"
else
  printf "You are not using a terminal.\n"
fi

tty -s && printf "Guten Tag.\n"
```

Output after `./tty.sh` command:

```
You are not using a terminal.
Guten Tag.
```

Output in test.txt after `./tty.sh > test.txt`:
```
Youre not using a terminal.
Guten Tag.
```

Comment: The basic syntax part here is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371221/checking-the-success-of-a-command-in-a-bash-if-statement - you are testing whether `tty -s` outputs a non-empty string, which it simply doesn't, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that if statements in bash checks the exit status of the provided command:

```
if command; then
  # then block
else
  # else block
fi
```

and `[[` is just a special built-in command.

Simply use:

```
if tty -s; then
```

To run some code when `tty -s` exists with an exit status of 0, (success)

And also instead of using the `tty` to check if the input is a terminal, use `[ -t 0 ]` instead.

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
```

See `man 1 tty` and `man 1 test`.

In case it wasn't clear from the `man 1 test`, then you can test if standard output and standard error output is a terminal with, respectively:

```
[ -t 1 ] # stdout is a terminal
[ -t 2 ] # stderr is a terminal
```

Comment: While this is a good answer the code suggested here will still be executed when I redirect the output to a file.

Comment: If you are interested in testing your output then you can change to `[ -t 1 ]`

Comment: @theerrormagnet If you want to test that all streams are connected to a terminal, you could do `[ -t 0 ] && [ -t 1 ] && [ -t 2 ]`