# Bash: For loops inside for loops

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement, pdf

I can not make this simple script work in bash

```
# Works
for f in *; do
    for j in $f/Attachments/*.pdf; do 
        echo "$j"
    done;
done

# Doesn't work  
for f in *; do
    for j in $f/Attachments/*.pdf; do 
        if [ ! pdfinfo "$j" &> /dev/null ]; then
            echo "$j"
        fi
    done;
done
```

I have read 10+ guides, and I cannot understand why this script lists a bunch of random directories.

It should:

1. List folders in the current directory
2. In each folder it should list all PDF-files in the subdirectory Attachments
3. For each file it should check if it is corrupt, and if so print it

Comment: The problem isn't the `for` loops, it's that the condition in the `if` statement is garbled. See ["Checking the success of a command in a bash `if [ .. ]` statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371221/checking-the-success-of-a-command-in-a-bash-if-statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want could be achieved by this code snippet:

```
for f in */Attachments/*.pdf; do
    if ! pdfinfo "$f" &>/dev/null; then
        echo "$f"
    fi
done
```

In your code, `for f in *` iterates through all files (including directories). If you want directories only, you must have used `for f in */`. Like that:

```
for d in */; do
    for f in "$d"Attachments/*.pdf; do
        [[ -f $f ]] || continue
        if ! pdfinfo "$f" &>/dev/null; then
            echo "$f"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not my use case, I am still building on the loop, and I have to do operations at the folder-level, not the file-level.

Comment: @See updated answer.

Comment: In my case the directory i am iterating over only contains directories already :)

Comment: Your code also outputs: directory/Attachments/*.pdf - It should only be files that exist, not *.pdf. But your code actually runs!

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt Just added a test for file existence.