# How to Execute More Than One Command in a Single Shell Script?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, command

Hello to everyone as this is my first post here :)

I am a macOS user, and I am struggling with writing a script consisting of two commands to be interpreted and executed by the ZSH interpreter (the default interpreter on macOS Sonora and macOS Ventura preceding it).

The two commands mentioned are as follows:

1. A netstat command to continuously check whether Mac is connected to a particular server (in netstat known as "Foreign Address"). The syntax of this command is as follows:

`sudo tcpdump -n -k NP | grep xx.xxx.xx.xx`

where `xx.xxx.xx.xx` is the particular IP address of the server I am interested in, which is to be filtered out of all the other established connections using the `| grep` option. I must mention here that I had earlier added my user account, which is the only user account on my Mac, to the original sudoers file in the system, so that the ZSH interpreter does not prompt for the user password when executing the command, and can execute it seamlessly.

2. A negated, conditional `if statement` command with `killall` to kill a particular running process, and any other processes potentially related to it, if there is no connection with the server mentioned earlier. The syntax of this command is as follows:

```
if [[ ! sudo tcpdump -n -k NP | grep xx.xxx.xx.xx ]] then killall -9 “nameoftheprocesstobekilled”
fi
```

The statement is negated using the `!` sign in double square brackets.

When it comes to the first one of the two commands, when I run only that command alone in the Terminal, the command works perfectly well, being that the Terminal does not prompt for the user password due to my user account added to the sudoers file, and then continuously and concurrently displays the established connection with the particular server, rapidly refreshing and displaying the connection per individual lines, one after the other.

The problem arises if I want to execute both those commands together, and save them as such in a script file for future use. When I combine those two commands together, like this:

```
sudo tcpdump -n -k NP | grep xx.xxx.xx.xx && if [[ ! sudo tcpdump -n -k NP | grep xx.xxx.xx.xx ]] then killall -9 “nameoftheprocesstobekilled”
fi
```

the Terminal returns the following prompt:

`zsh: condition expected: sudo`

This prompt is not preceded by `zsh: parse error:` which suggests that it is not any kind of error. I had tried to look for `zsh: condition expected: sudo` on the Internet, and found no such exact phrase. Does anyone know what this prompt means? How come it is expecting `sudo`, as if it were not used, when it is used?

I have tried combining the two commands in other ways than using the the two ampersand signs as above, such as using the single semi colon sign right after the end of the first command, with the blank space between the end of that command and the semi colon, no such blank space, blank space after the semi colon and the beginning of the other command, as well as no such blank space, all to no avail - whichever of those configurations, the Terminal keeps prompting the same prompt. Writing those two commands in a single line, combined with whichever of the configurations described above, does not help either.

What should happen, is that executing the first command, the script should begin to continuously look for an established connection with the server I entered the IP address of, and if, for whatever reason, the connection with that server was lost, it should execute the other command, which should kill the running process indicated, along with whatever other processes related to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking the success of a command in a bash \`if \[ .. \]\` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371221/checking-the-success-of-a-command-in-a-bash-if-statement)

Comment: The duplicate is not 100% (talks about Bash, and `[...]` instead of `[[...]]`), but the solution applies.

Comment: Thank you, @BenjaminW. for suggesting the solution from this thread. It has solved my issue, but only to an extent. If I remove either one or both of the square brackets before `! sudo` and after `grep xx.xxx.xx.xx`, the first one of the commands seems to pass. However, now I am returned with a prompt message reading: `zsh: parse error near `fi'`` instead. What is worth mentioning here is that I am testing those commands without being connected to the server and also without the process to be killed running because I want to be absolutely sure everything works before put into practice.

Comment: `if [[ .... ]] ; then` is the correct syntax for single line `if` statement. (Note the semi-colon (`;`). But, you don't need the `[[ ]]` brackets. just `if ! cmd | cmd2 | ... ; then` should be able to work. ALSO you are using uni-code curly quotes; you need to use "straight" single ('`') and double (`"`) quotes. Probably other issues. Put `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of your code and then fix any errors found at https://shellcheck.net . Update your question with the corrected code. ....

Comment: ALSO way too much discussion. Requirements/Sample InputData/Output or Actions, Code and exact text of error msgs should speak for themselves (-; Good luck.

Comment: You might also want to look into the `PIPE_FAIL` zsh option. If it's not set, the exit status of `cmd1 | cmd2` is that of `cmd2`, even if `cmd1` failed. Often, you want the overall exit status to be non-zero (unsuccessful) when any command in the pipeline fails, and that's what this option is for.

Comment: Only if your `sudo ... | grep ...` sets exit status 0, you execute the `if`. This means that the `if` runs if the IP address is found in the output of tcpdump. Inside your `if`, you run the same command again, but negate the exit code of `sudo`. Since we have a pipe (into the grep), the negated exit code does not have any effect on the `if`. In fact you again execute the grep, and the `if` takes the true branch if the IP address is still found. Why are you repeating the identical command here?

Comment: @user1934428 As for repeating the command, the thing is that I didn't know how to express just the result of the first command, that is, the IP address found, so that I could negate that result in the other command and make it execute itself when that result is not met, that is, when the IP address is not found. I must admit that you are most certainly right that it would be wise to use the status `0` for when the result is met, and thus successful, and `1` for when it is not. I must emphasize, though, that I'm a self-taught script writer, and that this is my first script.

Comment: @user1934428 Continued: As it is, I concluded that using the negation as I did, I would make the other command execute itself when the IP was not found by the first command. Another issue would be how to exactly phrase that status you mentioned, and how to incorporate it within the two commands. Various tutorials are not specific as to how to phrase, put together and arrange various commands, and I found one in which it was said that it doesn't matter if you put `!` before `[ [`, or even within `[ [`, at its beginning. It was also that from which I inferred it should be `[ [`, and not `[`.

Comment: But the `[[` does not make sense. Inside your `if` you don't execute the `sudo`. For running it, you would have to write `if ! sudo ....`.

Comment: Well, the wording of the two commands is now exactly:

``
'#!/usr/bin/env zsh'
sudo tcpdump -n -k NP | grep xx.xxx.xx.xx | if ! sudo tcpdump -n -k NP | grep xx.xxx.xx.xx then killall -9 'thenameoftheprocesstobekilled'
set -o pipefail -e
fi
``

As you can see, without the double `[[ ...` and `... ]]`, and with the opening directory to the interpreter, which is to handle the commands. When I execute the two commands as is in the Terminal, I am returned with the following prompt: `zsh: parse error near `fi'`. The final process is within the single `'` now, so it's vague what's wrong.