# Check if a file does not exist with a wildcard in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, file, terminal, file-io

I want to run a set of commands only if there are no tar.gz files in the $DIR. I am trying to do this but the commands errors out

```
if [ ! compgen -G "$DIR/*.tar.gz"  > /dev/null ]; then { commands; } fi
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You could use `find "$MERGE_CHUNKS_TO_PATH" -maxdepth 1 -name '*.tar.gz'` and see if it returns anything.

Comment: Remove the square-brackets. Those are only used to evaluate a test expression, rather than the success (/failure) of a command, and here you're testing the success of the `compgen` command. See ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command) and ["Checking the success of a command in a bash `if [ .. ]` statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371221/checking-the-success-of-a-command-in-a-bash-if-statement).

Comment: It produces an error, becaus the parameters for your `[` command don't make sense. For the syntax of this command, do a `man test`. The bash version of `[` is basically an internal re-implementation for the external `test` command, with only tiny extensions; for your purpose, it is sufficient to study what `man test` is saying.